# Add images to a jframe

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jlabel

I keep trying all this example code and none of it works, it always wants me to have a try/catch which means I have to ini. the variable anyway and I am tearing my hair out on the one, I have a jframe the exact size of my image, all I want is it to fill the entire jframe, also, could you make it so that if the image is transparent, that you can see though the entire jframe.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("path/to/image.png"));
```

There is a class called `ImageIcon` that can be used for images in Swing. [Javadocs for `ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html)

[There are also many other ways to use `ImageIcon`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Comment: A BG to a frame will typically need to be accessed by by URL by time of deployment, and URL is also workable during development.  By making it 'so simple' as loading the image by file, this creates another problem down the road.

Answer (score 1):

From your saying that your example code want's you to use `try / catch` blocks, I'm guessing you are using the `ImageIO` class. It returns you with a `BufferedImage` which is not able to added to the frame. See the [`ImageIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) class here which you can use with the JLabel

```
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("my_image.png"));
```

This should work if your image is outside of your jar. If it's included in the jar, use the classloader to get the resource for you.

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("my_image.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
frame.add(new JLabel(icon));
```

Hope this works.